# Automating the screen recording of a web app for documentation purposes

Tags: web-apps, automation, video-recording

Using Selenium webdriver we can record an automated test of our web app to produce a video for documentation purposes ([example](https://youtu.be/58GI9MpiI2I)), but it could look far more polished & smoothly animated (webdriver doesn't have animated mouse movements)

Any suggestions for an alternative to Selenium webdriver we can use to target HTML elements for each action in the video?

- Features = needs to be able to program the recording (& save the program) to target specific HTML elements, which may change next time the web app GUI is updated (which means our documentation's videos need to be re-recorded with slightly altered HTML elements).
- Platform = macOS or Chrome
- OS = macOS
- Budget = perhaps US$100/month

Comment: Have you  looked at OBS https://obsproject.com/ ? That is what I would normally use and recommend for recordings.